# FM modulation - recovering bits

Tags: matlab, modulation, spectrogram, demodulation, frequency-modulation

I'm trying to complete one task:
Download some FM modulated signals from page http://www.w1hkj.com/modes/index.htm. Calculate their spectrograms, i.e. short-time Fourier transform. Observe different
FM patterns. Do some literature investigations. Try to recover bits that are coded by different frequency values (states).

At first I displayed a spectrogram:

```
clc; 
clear; 
close all;

[y,fs] = audioread('Olivia16-500.wav');
spectrogram(y, 512,256,512, fs, 'yaxis');
```

And the other part is: Try to recover bits that are coded by different frequency values (states). I guess I should demodulate signal, so I did the following:

```
Nx = length(y); 
n= 0:Nx-1;
dt = 1/fs;
t = dt*n;

fc=200;
figure(1)
z=demod(y,fc,fs,'fm');
plot(t,y, 'c', t,z, 'b');
xlabel('Time'); ylabel('Amplitude');
legend('Modulated signal', 'Recovered signal');
```

And the output:

[image]

Did I understand the task correctly or did I miss something? Thank you for any advices.

Comment: you say you should be getting bits, but I don't see bits being output anywhere, so this might be a step in the right direction, but it's not the answer. Other than that, you're asking us to verify you understood an assignment correctly that we've never seen but only heard from you about – and your reproduction of the problem will likely contain the same mistakes in understanding you want to ask about, so this is inanswerable!

Comment: I edited my question by adding exact description of the task

Comment: I don't believe any of the signals in the page you linked are frequency modulated.

Comment: @MBaz I also have doubts but it's from my professor's book and there is: `Examples of different FM modulated HAM signals and their spectra are presented in w1hkj.com/modes/index.htm.`

Comment: Why don't ask your professor then? I'm sure (s)he'll be happy to help you.

Comment: @MBaz it's an exam task so I am not supposed to ask my professor about it haha

Comment: Most professors accept clarification questions, in my experience. Ask something like "Excuse me, but the description of the signals in the provided link indicate that they are BPSK modulated; could you confirm that the link is correct?"

Comment: @MBaz but there are digital signals, so if I use some FSK modulated signals (i.e. Olivia Mode) isn't it like FM?

Comment: I don't know.  --